# Fundamental solution of a particular differential operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Show that he distribution given by the locally integrable function $\dfrac{1}{2} e^{|x|}$ is a fundamental solution of the differential operator 
$\begin{equation}
-\dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + id
\end{equation}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check directly by noting the fact that 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}e^{|x|}=(H(x)+H(-x))e^{|x|}
$$
where H is the Heaviside function.
On the other hand,you can use fourier transform to get the desired result,in fact,let u satisfies
$$
(1-\frac{d}{dx^2})u=\delta
$$
Take fourier transform on both sides,then get 
$$
\hat{u}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$
then the result follows easily.